# What algorithms can I use to make inferences from a graph?

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics, machine-learning

**Edited question to make it a bit more specific.**

Not trying to base it on content of nodes but solely of structure of directed graph.

For example, pagerank(at first) solely used the link structure(directed graph) to make inferences on what was more relevant.  I'm not totally sure, but I think Elo(chess ranking) does something simlair to rank players(although it adds scores also).

I'm using python's networkx package but right now I just want to understand any algorithms that accomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for more general information to solve generic problems.  I understand edges are a way of doing it, but was trying to see if there were others or is it all specific to my problem set?

Comment: sorry, maybe I misread your question, here's an example, say my customers are ordering something from me everyday.  I have a list of orders from day1 and a list of orders from day2(and edges connecting customers orders together).  Can I use graphs to predict what the likely purchase is on day3?

Comment: It usually depends on your problem. I've seen people use various parameters like degree, average shortest path length, centrality, etc. to define probabilities.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!  I'm trying to understand which parameters(like you wrote or mix of parameters) and when they are useful. Most of the examples out there are used to repent the data structure and not make inferences on it.  It would help to understand the extents I could use graphs for inferences.

Comment: In that case, this is more of a math problem. You need to define how you derive the probability of day 3 with respect to the information you already have. Then the graph could be just a tool to calculate numerical values.

Comment: I understand applying specific math to values in the nodes but I'm approaching this strictly as a graph nodes(i.e. states).  Say day1, you bought milk(node), day2 you bought beer(node), can I use graphs to predict you'll buy something else(If I have other users in the same graph as well)?   It may not be possible with graphs, I'm not sure which is why I'm asking.

Comment: your last comment sounds similar to [what Netflix does](http://www.netflixprize.com/) i.e., movie1 on day1, movie2 on day2, what movie on day3?

Comment: I'm not sure if they are using graphs or not, but the exercises I did in the book 'Programming Collective Intelligence' didn't use any for generating a recommendation system.  Graphs were somewhat used in the implementation of pagerank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Eigenvector centrality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Eigenvector_centrality) is a network metric that can be used to model the probability that a node will be encountered in a random walk. It factors in not only the number of edges that a node has but also the number of edges the nodes it connects to have and onward with the edges that the nodes connected to its connected nodes have and so on. It can be implemented with a random walk which is how Google's [PageRank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank) algorithm works.

That said, the field of [network analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_theory) is broad and continues to develop with new and interesting research. The way you ask the question implies that you might have a different impression. Perhaps start by looking over the three links I included here and see if that gets you started and then follow up with more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it hit me this morning that page rank is exactly what I was asking for but wanted to know if there was more. Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

You should probably take a look at [Markov Random Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_random_field) and [Conditional Random Fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_random_field). Perhaps the closest thing similar to what you're describing is a [Bayesian Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network)